# How to go back in conversation steps in Watson Assistant actions?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I'm trying to set up an action where users can go back a step, but there seems to be an issue when I click 'Back' as the action ends.

As shown in the screenshots, 'Back' meets the conditions to trigger step 2 but it doesn't work.

If I change 'Continue to next step' to 'Re-ask previous step(s)' then step 2 re-directs to step 1 when clicking on 'Back', but doesn't continue to step 3 when clicking on 'Measures...'.

[image]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Can you add more details about the action you've created. Can you include a screen shot of all steps?
I assume step 4 has a condition checking if the user said "Back" at step 3, and is doing some sort of "re-ask" logic? It would be good if you can show a screen cap of all steps to give more context - thanks

Comment: Hi Dan, I didn't have the re-ask, that's where I went wrong. Now I have included a catch-all re-ask at the bottom of the action so I can use the 'Back' option throughout the option. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common issue for this is in the reask. When you select the reask you will need to select all the steps that you want to reask.

If you don't select a step then the previous value still stays there.

So if you reask looks like this, then it won't work as the `Back` step is still set to `Back`.

[image: Only step 2 is selected.]

You need to set it to this:

[image: Step 2 and 3 is selected]

In the earlier version of Actions it would not click all by default. The current version does. So you might have accidentally clicked it off.

So your steps should look something like this:

[image: Picture of steps. See attachment for more details]

I have put an [example assistant](https://github.com/sodoherty-ai/blog_scripts/blob/master/stackoverflow/76087875-1167890_Go-Back-Example.json) up on Github.

Comment: This is an excellent example, thank you, Simon! I missed step four. As I wanted to include a 'Back' option for each step, I didn't want to do this for each step. So I included a catch-all at the bottom of the action which seems to work well, as shown here: https://imgur.com/a/pan7oSU

Comment: Just to let you know that Actions has whats called "Reverse slotting". The user does not need to go back, they can change the option by just saying it.  For example if you were on 3 in my answer and said "I meant Chapter 2" it would change step 2 (assuming there is a chapter 2 option) then rerun steps based on that change.

Comment: Thanks Simon, totally agree. The long-term plan is to remove the explicit 'Back' option so that things are more natural.